# Remove rows with conflicting labels

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Say I have a table that looks like this:

```
A   B 
1   bull 
1   bull 
1   pug 
1   bull 
2   pug 
2   pug 
3   dane 
3   dane 
4   shepherd
```

I am looking for a one liner to remove rows with conflicting labels. In the case above, the rows labeled 1 while be removed leaving others regardless of the duplicates. My current attempt is a few lines and failing in some cases.

Comment: Is there always one value that conflicts or can it be multiple and if so do you want to keep the highest count?

Comment: @Chris I'd like to remove the entirety of the rows once there is a conflict. For it to remain, all duplicates must have the same value. So, there won't be need for the highest count

Comment: The answer posted is what you are looking for then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `nunique` with `transform`

```
df[df.groupby('A').B.transform('nunique')==1]
   A         B
4  2       pug
5  2       pug
6  3      dane
7  3      dane
8  4  shepherd
```

---

You can also use `groupby` and `nunique`, retaining rows with unique count as 1.

```
df[df.A.map(df.groupby('A').B.nunique()).eq(1)]

   A         B
4  2       pug
5  2       pug
6  3      dane
7  3      dane
8  4  shepherd
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `.filter` for these sorts of problems:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas
data = StringIO("""\
A   B 
1   bull 
1   bull 
1   pug 
1   bull 
2   pug 
2   pug 
3   dane 
3   dane 
4   shepherd
""")

df = (
    pandas.read_csv(data, sep='\s+')
        .groupby(by=['A'])
        .filter(lambda g: g['B'].nunique() == 1)
)
print(df)
```

And I get:

```
   A         B
4  2       pug
5  2       pug
6  3      dane
7  3      dane
8  4  shepherd
```